# why "could not find SDK "BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged, Version-12.0"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I developed a xamarin native project and it was working fine then suddenly started throwing some compilation errors for UWP alone.

Earlier the same UWP was working fine.
I cloned the project in new machine. I am getting this error.

Please refer image for more details.

[image]

Comment: `Could not find SDK` check the path to the SDK or download one

Comment: Did you try Removing **BehaviorsXAMLSDKmanaged** from references in UWP and build again ?

Answer (score 3):

Removing ***BehaviorsXAMLSDKmanaged*** from references in UWP project fixed the issue for me.